# copy entire directory but exclude some files php

Tags: php

trying to find a way to copy entire directory but exclude certain files, in this case just need to exclude a directory which will always contain just 1 file a png... figured could use something similar to this code but have absolutely no clue as to how to exclude a file only

```
function xcopy($source, $dest, $permissions = 0755)
{
    // Check for symlinks
    if (is_link($source)) {
        return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
    }

    // Simple copy for a file
    if (is_file($source)) {
        return copy($source, $dest);
    }

    // Make destination directory
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest, $permissions);
    }

    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        // Deep copy directories
        xcopy("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry", $permissions);
    }

    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that may work for you. I have notated for clarification:

```
<?php
    function CopyDirectory($settings = false)
        {
            // The script may take some time if there are lots of files
            ini_set("max_execution_time",3000);
            // Just do some validation and pre-sets
            $directory  =   (isset($settings['dir']) && !empty($settings['dir']))? $settings['dir'] : false;
            $copyto     =   (isset($settings['dest']) && !empty($settings['dest']))? $settings['dest'] : false;
            $filter     =   (isset($settings['filter']) && !empty($settings['filter']))? $settings['filter'] : false;
            // Add the copy to destinations not to copy otherwise
            // you will have an infinite loop of files being copied
            $filter[]   =   $copyto;
            // Stop if the directory is not set
            if(!$directory)
                return;
            // Create a recursive directory iterator
            $dir        =   new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory),RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

            try{ 
                foreach($dir as $file) {
                        $copydest   =   str_replace("//","/",$copyto."/".str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"",$file));
                        $compare    =   rtrim($file,".");
                        if(is_dir($file)) {
                                if(!is_dir($copydest)) {
                                        if(!in_array($compare,$filter)) {
                                                if(isset($skip) && !preg_match("!".$skip."!",$file) || !isset($skip))
                                                    @mkdir($copydest,0755,true);
                                                else
                                                    $record[]   =   $copydest;
                                            }
                                        else {
                                                $skip       =   $compare;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                        elseif(is_file($file) && !in_array($file,$filter)) {
                                copy($file,$copydest);
                            }
                        else {
                                if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
                                    $record[]   =   $copydest;
                            }
                    }
                }
            // This will catch errors in copying (like permission errors)
            catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    $error[]    =   $e;
                }
        }

    // Copy from
    $settings['dir']        =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    // Copy to
    $settings['dest']       =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tester";
    // Files and folders to not include contents
    $settings["filter"][]   =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core.processor/';
    $settings["filter"][]   =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php';
    $settings["filter"][]   =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/client_assets/images/';

    // Create instance
    CopyDirectory($settings);
?>
```

Comment: just tried it works like a gloove,,, i was wondering if its possible to have it copy only the contents, like all folders inside the 'dir' to the 'dest' folder. it is copying entire folder from dir to dest

Comment: You want just the folder structure? Just make a new setting and modify the code a bit in then copy & mkdir parts

Comment: i did, hadnt checked here, man you worth millions, ty very much