# How to exclude a folder from php copy command?

Tags: php, file, copy

I want to copy a folder which has child folders, but excluding one folder.

Ex: my folder doc/themes  , doc/images, doc/js , doc/others

I want to copy folder 'doc' with all its sub folders but excluding 'images' folder and all files listed under 'images'
please advice

below is my code

```
$tCopy->copy($docPath , $newPath, array('folderPermission'=>0777,'filePermission'=>0777));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy entire directory but exclude some files php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836521/copy-entire-directory-but-exclude-some-files-php)