# Exclude files and folders when copying

Tags: php, copy

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836521/copy-entire-directory-but-exclude-some-files-php), but it doesn't get me anywhere. I would like to be able to exclude certain files with relative paths from being copied, but the whole thing no longer works with subdirectories, so far I have only shown what subdirectories cannot be excluded without copying:

```
     class MyRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {

    //exluded Files and dirs
    public static $FILTERS = array(
        'config' => '',
    );

    public function accept() {
        return !in_array(
            $this->current()->getFilename(),
            self::$FILTERS,
            true
        );
    }

}

$dirItr    = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../dir1');
$filterItr = new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($dirItr);
$itr       = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filterItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($itr as $filePath => $fileInfo) {
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: That answer seems to be working with sub directories. Could you show what kind of error you are getting on this case?

Comment: There is no error, but if I have a subfolder "config" with files in it and exclude it, it works, but if I now have another folder "test" in the folder "config" and I want to exclude it, all files are displayed again which are in the test folder, the filter is not applied

Comment: Using the code from the question/answer you referenced, how did you set this `test` folder in your `$settings["filter"]` ?

Comment: $settings["filter"] = "dir1/config/test"; My source folder is "dir1"

Comment: Have you tried with the full path and with a slash `/` by the end? I.e: `$settings["filter"] = "/home/user/www/dir1/config/test/";` Where "/home/user/www/" is where your app base folder is located on your system.

Comment: Yes, the filter is still not applied, I am surprised myself, I cannot exclude files either

Comment: Try `echoing` the folders you are filtering and the ones you are trying to remove the files from. Compare both and give us the differences.

Comment: I found my solution in a symfony class [link](https://insphpect.com/report/class/5e63a92291af4/Symfony%5CComponent%5CFinder%5CIterator%5CExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator). I changed the code a little to support subdirectories and it works, now all that's missing is copying